# How to pass Criteria to an Array in Yii

Tags: php, yii, criteria

I have the following queries..

```
$Provider1 = new CSqlDataProvider($Query1, array('pagination'=>false));
$Result1 = $bProvider->getData();

$Provider2 = new CSqlDataProvider($Query2, array('pagination'=>false));
$Result2 = $bProvider->getData();
```

Then im merging both array results

```
$Result = array_merge($Result1, $Result2);
```

As this array `$Result` contains multiple records like 100+

Here is what i have tried for pagination

```
// Counting array result for pagination
    $item_count = count($timelineResult);
    $page_size = 10;
    $pages = new CPagination($item_count);
    $pages->setPageSize($page_size);

    $end = ($pages->offset + $pages->limit <= $item_count ? $pages->offset + $pages->limit : $item_count);

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->limit = $end;
    $criteria->offset = $pages->offset;
```

Now the problem is how do i apply this `$criteria` to my `$Result`

Comment: Maybe use http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider instead CPagination and CDbCriteria. U can put array into it and set pagination in constructor. CDbCriteria is used to queries not when u already have result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you should use `CArrayDataProvider`. You already have a result in an array called `$Result` and remove the `CDbCriteria` from your pagination code, so it will be like this.

```
$item_count = count($Result);
$page_size = 10;
$pages = new CPagination($item_count);
$pages->setPageSize($page_size);
```

The `$page_size = 10` and we have to use the same page size 10 for CArrayDataProvider, Here is how you will use `CArrayDataProvider`:

```
$dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($Result, array(
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>$page_size,
        ),
    ));
```

and then get the result in an array like this..

```
$MyResult = $dataProvider->getData();
```

I hope it will work for you.